# cannot import name 'DISTILBERT_PRETRAINED_MODEL_ARCHIVE_MAP' from 'transformers.modeling_distilbert'

Tags: python, neural-network, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering, distilbert

I am trying to train the distil BERT model for Question Answering purpose. 
I have installed simple transformers and everything but when I try to run the following command:

```
model = QuestionAnsweringModel('distilbert', 
                               MODEL_PATH, 
                              args={'reprocess_input_data': True,
                                    'overwrite_output_dir': True,
                                    'learning_rate': 5e-5,
                                     'num_train_epochs': 2,
                                     'max_seq_length': 192,
                                   'doc_stride': 64,
                                   'fp16': False
                                  }, use_cuda=use_cuda)
```

I am getting the error - >

```
cannot import name 'DISTILBERT_PRETRAINED_MODEL_ARCHIVE_MAP' 
from 'transformers.modeling_distilbert' 
(/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_distilbert.py)
```

please help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the version of transformer,after I update transformer===2.7.0,it works.